# Javascript: how can I redirect to a url or another url after checking if user input specific words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, redirect

I'm tryng to achieve if user input on id "comments" is word that is present in my FilterWord's array then user will be redirected to an url.
If input is anything else, then user will be redirected to another url.

Checking has to start after user click on submit.

```js
var buttonPress = function () {
  var com = document.getElementById('comments');
  var filterWords = ["apple", "yellow", "melon", "blue", "red"];
  // "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global
  var rgx = new RegExp("("+filterWords.join("|")+")", "gi");
        
  if (com.value == rgx) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
  }
};
```

```html
<form name="words" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return buttonPress();">
  <textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  <br />
  <input id="formSub" type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

Comment: `com.value == rgx` that is not how reg exp works. You want match, test, execute, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just validate with some.

```
var buttonPress = function () {
    var com = document.getElementById('comments');
    var filterWords = ["apple", "yellow", "melon", "blue", "red"];
    
    var exists = filterWords.some(word => word == com.value);
            
    if (exists) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    } else {
        window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
    }

    return false;
};
```

Comment: Need a `return false` also or form will submit

Comment: Thanks Byron, sorry but I couldn't validate with your code. Can you please modify my code so I will understand what's wrong? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttonPress = function () {
  var com = document.getElementById('comments');
  var filterWords = ["apple", "yellow", "melon", "blue", "red"];
  // "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global
  var rgx = new RegExp("("+filterWords.join("|")+")", "gi");
    
  if (rgx.test(com.value) {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regExp `.test()` should fit your problem. Check the documentation. [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#other_methods)

> If you need to know if a string matches a regular expression RegExp, use RegExp.test().

Working Code:

```
var buttonPress = function() {
  var com = document.getElementById('comments');
  var filterWords = ["apple", "yellow", "melon", "blue", "red"];
  var rgx = new RegExp("(" + filterWords.join("|") + ")", "gi");

  if (rgx.test(com.value)) {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could set a array of object, like :

```
filterWords = [
{ word : "apple" , target : "apple.com"},
{ word : "orange" , target : "orange.com"}
]
```

and in function press :

```
   var com = document.getElementById('comments');
   // loop above array
   filterWords.foreach(obj => {
   // check if string input has word, and redirect
    if(com.includes(obj.word))
     window.location.href = obj.target ;
   })
   // if not match, redirect to default url
     window.location.href = "http://www.bing.com";
```